# Making math.random with float values

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I've got a little function, which allows to receive some integer which must be percentage value (0-100), and rolls some chance to understand if it's currently true or not (roll):

```
function RollV (value) {
        var rollvalue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1),
        result = true;
        if (value >= rollvalue) {
            result = true;
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

From what I understand, this func will not return `true` with float `value`, because random `rollvalue` couldn't be float, like if I want to use 0.001% chance, this will not be passed as `true`, is there any ways to make math random with float values?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7nbv2nrd/

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a random number greater than or equal to zero and less than 1.  The code you've got uses that to pick a random integer, but there's nothing inherent about `Math.random()` that limits you to integers.

Comment: Also please just `return value >= rollvalue`

Comment: your result is a global variable, add `var` before it.

Comment: What mplungjan said, or even `return value >= Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)`. It's really not a complicated enough calculation to need an intermediate variable, unless you need to log it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
 (Math.random() * (upper_limit - lower_limit) + lower_limit).toFixed(3)
```

**Update**

As @Pointy said, this will return string and if you want it to be float you can use parseFloat(value) or .toFixed()

**Edit**

`Math.random()` result is float by default and if you don't want to set a limit ( let's say your ok with values from 0 to 1 ), than remove `Math.floor` from your code

Comment: It should be noted that this code will return a **string**, not a number.

Comment: You don't have to use `.parseFloat()`; you can simply skip the call to `.toFixed()`.

Comment: There's not really any need to use `toFixed()`, because the random number doesn't ever get displayed, it just gets compared to whatever is passed into the `value` argument. (I realise the demo fiddle does display it, but that seems like a testing thing, not a real requirement of the problem as described.)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lty39re4/)

```
function RollV(value) {
    var rollvalue = Math.random();
    $('.result').text(rollvalue);
    return value >= rollvalue;
}

console.log(0.01,RollV(0.01));
```